# How to convert Countvectorized data back to text data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

how can I convert count vectorized text data back to textual form. I have text data which I had made into sparse matrix using countvectorizer for classification. Now I want the sparse martix of text data to be converted back into  text data.

**My code**

```
 cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 500,analyzer='word') 
    cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))

    for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
        data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_addr[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: You want the *original text back*? That's impossible, vector-space representations loose all positional information. There's no way to tell "the dog ate the cat" from "the cat ate the dog" from "ate dog the cat the"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga,I have done address classification using address text data and  some  other numeric data columns. Now I have classified them two  categories bassically(Business & Residential).How can I understand which was properly classified  and which not classified.Sklearn doesnt accept text data  as such into decision tree

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't sound related to your question at all...? What exactly is the problem? You are working with labeled data, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, How can I understand which record was classified properly and which not classified  properly. I had Splitted dataset into test and train. These datasets contains only numeric values .

Comment: Yes. But you *have the labels, no?*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have labelled dataset with columns such as address , qty,weight, phone number  type and Address Delivery flag( B/R). I am trying to predict address delivery flag  with other columns and I have successfully classified  them into B/R.In short, How to match B/R flag with orginal address

Comment: Then you should be able to simply check if your predicted flag is the same as your actual flag, no?

Comment: .In short, How to match B/R flag with original address

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have no primary keys in the train and test data. So how can I find which correctly and which wrongly classified

Comment: @ashokeapen, can you post a small sample data set and your desired data set? This would help us to understand what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: Primary keys? When you split the training sets, you should have kept the indices, **that is your key**

Comment: @MaxU,I have updated  sample data

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga,OK got it now.Thanks Mate

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible - all punctuations, spaces, tabs have been removed. Also all words have been converted to lower case. AFAIK there is no way to get it back in the original format. So you'd better keep `Clean_addr` column instead of dropping it.

Demo:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
                                         txt
0                              a sample text
1  to be, or not to be, that is the question

In [19]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [20]: cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 500, analyzer='word')

In [21]: cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(df['txt'])

In [22]: x = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv_addr, columns=cv.get_feature_names(), 
                                index=df.index, default_fill_value=0)

In [23]: x
Out[23]:
   be  is  not  or  question  sample  text  that  the  to
0   0   0    0   0         0       1     1     0    0   0
1   2   1    1   1         1       0     0     1    1   2

In [24]: df.join(x)
Out[24]:
                                         txt  be  is  not  or  question  sample  text  that  the  to
0                              a sample text   0   0    0   0         0       1     1     0    0   0
1  to be, or not to be, that is the question   2   1    1   1         1       0     0     1    1   2
```